# R - not all elements returned (for loop)

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

The following simple loop seems to skip elements in a data frame. I would appreciate any tips in figuring out where the problem with the data/code may lay.

```
foo <- apply(data, 1, function(x) {

    vec <- x
    mylist <- list()

    for (i in vec){
        #print(i)
        mylist[[i]]<-i
    }
    print(length(vec))
    print(length(mylist))
})
```

My data frame has 25 columns. For *some* rows, `length(vec)` returns 25, while `length(mylist)` returns 24.

```
[1] 25
[1] 24
```

If I use the hashed-out `print(i)` I can see 25 elements in all rows.

The above is a simplification of the actual code I want to use, but the problem already occurs in this simple format.

Thanks in advance!

PS. I have tried having data as character or as factor. Neither seems to impact the problem.

PPS. two lines of the data frame that give different results (although they contain the same number of elements):

```
 structure(list(data1.LOC = c("LL_A1_00000003068_686", "LL_A1_00000003538_274"), REF = c("G", "T"), ALT = c("C", "C"), L47.variant = c("0/1:28,34:62:99:1154,0,926", "0/0:9,0:9:21:0,21,276"), L51.variant = c("0/0:61,0:61:99:0,184,2417", "0/0:6,0:6:15:0,15,192"), LCro11.variant = c("0/0:24,0:24:72:0,72,951", "0/0:2,0:2:6:0,6,80"), LCro5.variant = c("0/0:48,0:48:99:0,141,1869", "0/0:5,0:5:15:0,15,173"), N01.variant = c("0/1:22,16:38:99:526,0,758", "1/1:0,2:2:6:63,6,0"), N09.variant = c("1/1:1,50:51:99:1885,110,0", "0/0:12,0:12:36:0,36,460"), Nor28.variant = c("1/1:0,23:23:66:874,66,0", "0/0:5,0:5:12:0,12,159"), P161.variant = c("1/1:0,54:55:99:2118,163,0", "0/0:2,0:2:6:0,6,80"), Rom155.variant = c("0/0:69,0:69:99:0,208,2749", "0/1:5,3:8:99:102,0,102"), Rom161.variant = c("0/0:75,0:75:99:0,226,2957", "0/0:5,0:5:15:0,15,196"), Rom303.variant = c("0/0:44,0:44:99:0,132,1739", "0/0:5,0:5:15:0,15,195"), Rus291.variant = c("0/1:43,30:73:99:972,0,1443", "0/1:1,3:4:28:108,0,28"), Rus292.variant = c("0/0:56,0:56:99:0,163,2139", "0/0:11,0:11:33:0,33,429"), Sl5t.variant = c("0/1:55,34:89:99:1003,0,1911", "0/0:10,0:10:30:0,30,379"), Sl6t.variant = c("0/0:89,0:89:99:0,268,3513", "0/0:10,0:10:30:0,30,383"), s037y.variant = c("0/0:63,0:63:99:0,190,2484", "0/0:8,0:8:18:0,18,236"), s087y.variant = c("0/0:72,0:72:99:0,211,2770", "0/0:6,0:6:15:0,15,179"), s2E03.variant = c("0/1:34,27:61:99:810,0,1175", "0/0:4,0:4:12:0,12,143"), s2L05.variant = c("0/0:56,0:56:99:0,169,2220", "0/1:4,4:8:95:139,0,95"), s2P01.variant = c("0/1:44,27:71:99:859,0,1519", "0/0:6,0:6:18:0,18,240"), s2R01.variant = c("1/1:0,68:68:99:2642,202,0", "0/1:5,6:11:99:202,0,130"), s2R05.variant = c("0/1:41,33:74:99:1012,0,1393", "0/0:8,0:8:24:0,24,312")), .Names = c("data1.LOC", "REF", "ALT", "L47.variant", "L51.variant", "LCro11.variant", "LCro5.variant", "N01.variant", "N09.variant", "Nor28.variant", "P161.variant", "Rom155.variant", "Rom161.variant", "Rom303.variant", "Rus291.variant", "Rus292.variant", "Sl5t.variant", "Sl6t.variant", "s037y.variant", "s087y.variant", "s2E03.variant", "s2L05.variant", "s2P01.variant", "s2R01.variant", "s2R05.variant"), row.names = 19:20, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Generally, you want to assign to a list like `mylist[[i]] <- i` Not sure if that'll resolve this, though. Also, while it's good that you simplified your problem, it is also important in cases like this to provide a reproducible example (with data as well): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259

Comment: thank you for fast response! I have added two rows of the data frame. saddly, your suggestion did not help (but thanks!)

Comment: Please share your data with `dput()`, getting the proper underlying structure is probably important on this.

Comment: i am a bit confused about the `mylist[[i]] <- i` bit. according to your sample columns not all entries in a row would be integers so it won't be possible to use them as indices in `mylist`.

Comment: @stasg You can use character indices too.

Comment: You may have duplicates in `vec`. If for instance, `vec<-c(1,1,2)`, `length(vec)==3` but it will result that `length(mylist)==2`.

Comment: have added data using `dput()` .. sry, didnt klnow about this ability

Comment: Confirmed my hypothesis. If `x` is the object you provided, try `y<-as.matrix(x);length(y[1,]);length(y[2,])`.

Comment: @nicola is right. try `duplicated(as.character(x[1, ]))` and `duplicated(as.character(x[2, ]))`. you will see that the second row has two identical columns (there is one 'TRUE' value).

Comment: @ nicola  could you suggest a way for me to modify the script, if it is due to duplication?

Comment: I think the first step would be to convert your data into a usable format. The huge number of columns looks very unwieldy. I'd suggest you have a look at `library(data.table); res <- melt(setDT(x), measure.vars=patterns("variant"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using elements of `vec` to access elements of `mylist`, thus updating the same element in case of duplicates in `vec`, you should iterate through `vec` one by one via a standard integer index `i` running the length of it, like so:

```
foo <- apply(data, 1, function(x) {

     vec <- x
     mylist <- list()

     for (i in seq(vec)){
        #print(i)
         mylist[[i]] <- vec[i]
}
     print(length(vec))
     print(length(mylist))
})
```

To summarise, your code did not work because:  You may have duplicates in `vec`. If for instance, `vec<-c(1,1,2), length(vec)==3` but it will result that `length(mylist)==2`. # Comment from   nicola 1 hour ago

Comment: thanks a bunch!! this has been driving me crazy.  I implemented your suggestion for the large input file, and it worked a charm

Comment: Words explaining the change and why the OP's approach didn't work as expected would be good...

Comment: @nicola's comment above is the explanation.